# Should I assume I have passed probation?

Tags: canada, probation

My probationary period passed three days ago, I have not been told if I passed it, and I have my evaluation early next week. Should I assume that I have passed probation?

Answer (score 66):

Check your contract.  As a fellow Canadian, usually when I've seen probation contracts, the probation period is set by a specified number of days, not by an evaluation procedure.  If that's what your contract looks like, then congratulations, you passed!

I have never had a formal meeting in any job to discuss passing probation; I have only had such a meeting when I failed it.  If you are confused, you should ask your manager, but your manager will probably think you're being silly (not in a bad way, just in a "isn't it obvious?" way).

Comment: The most obvious way to fail a probation is they fire you.  If you're not fired, the you really didn't fail it that badly.  That's the entire point of the probation anyways.

Comment: I have had two post-probation meetings (different jobs) upon successfully passing it, so it's not unheard of. It was tied to a quarterly 1-on-1 with the manager, but that was the explicit theme of it.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen that's the point though. If it is succesful, there is no problem having those meetings after probation ended. If it wasn't succesful, it is too late for the company to act on it after probation ended, because the employee can't be fired at will anymore.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen I had (although in Germany) once a meeting to terminate my probation period early: it was shortened after 4 months and I was unconditionally employed as if the six months were over.

Answer (score 17):

> I have not been told if i passed it and have my evaluation early next
>   week should I assume that i have passed probation?

No.

Your evaluation will tell you whether you have passed probation or not. Be patient.

Comment: Is this for Canada? Because other answer tells something different. In Europe is like you said.

Comment: @BЈовић No, in Europe is not like that, at least not in Italy or the Netherlands, which is where I have been hired. If no-one says you're out then you're still in, no evaluation (and I have been in quite a few different companies).

Comment: @ChatterOne In every job I have been, every boss came too me and said that I passed the probation. Never happened like to the OP

Comment: @BЈовић in UK and Spain I have never been explicitly told I've passed probation either. Which European countries do you have experience working in?

Comment: This is not true in Canada.  If the probationary period is over, you are necessarily no longer in probation.  OP cannot somehow be retroatively terminated without severance within the probationary period.  The probation period is fixed and must be within the legal maximum set by the province.  https://singhlamarche.com/probation-periods-canada-mean/ is a good resource for some basic detail.  And I would honestly be surprised if it is significantly different elsewhere -- the entire point of setting a precise period of time for initial probation is for it to be applicable to that time alone.

Comment: @AaronF Netherlands, Belgium, Germany

Comment: @BЈовић You should look at your contract. Sure, the boss always told me (of course, don't people talk to their boss?), but if they didn't, my contract still makes it clear that if I'm not fired before the probation period the contract is automatically extended to full time.

Comment: @BЈовић an extension of the probation over 6 months is not legal in Germany [source](https://www.afa-anwalt.de/arbeitsrecht-ratgeber/probezeit/). If your probation period was shorter and your contract allows that - ok, but if 6 months are over - you are out of it.

Comment: @pipe Not telling that the probation was extended (it is not). What I said is that in every job, boss informed me that my probation was over.

Answer (score 12):

Judging by the fact that you haven't been let go, I'd say you pretty much have but I'd wait for an official word from your manager or someone higher up. Usually you should be invited to a meeting to discuss your performance.

Answer (score 7):

No you should not assume that you have passed probation.  You will likely be informed of the results of your probationary period during your evaluation.

Answer (score 6):

It depends where you are and the applicable laws, as well as what may (or not) be stated in your employment contract. In some places, you will likely need some confirmation that your probation period has been completed, in others it is the law that after a set number of days your probation has been completed by default.

In the latter case, you would now be a permanent employee and the termination process can become quite different. If the company wanted to let you go but missed the deadline, too bad for them, they need to comply with the laws that apply to an employee who is not on probation. This doesn't mean that they can't make your work life difficult, but the legal situation changes. In most cases, it is clear long before the end of a probation period whether a person is a good fit to the position/company.

Sometimes companies try to exploit the probationary period as a short-term employment position by terminating on, or just before, the last day, because the requirements and remuneration are different (more favourable to the company) than employing a contractor.

In the former case, it would be usual to have the meeting/conversation some days prior to the end of the probation period, otherwise it is possibly *"within some reasonable period of time"*, and then your best option is probably to say something like, *"hey boss, my probation was up last week," either before or at the evaluation meeting.

Answer (score 2):

Never make any assumptions.  Talk to your manager, mention that the period ended, and ask if you need to fill out any paperwork, or if there is an official review involved.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why they would have that conversation with you *now*. They're doing an evaluation next week, and that is the ideal place for that conversation.

I would expect them to tell you then.  In the meantime, bring your A-game.

Answer (score -1):

You should wait until any official confirmation.

I had a similar situation 4 months back, the confirmation meeting was delayed because of too much work.
Since you know your meeting is next week, you should wait until then.
In the meantime, you can take feedback from other colleagues about your performance to ease the pressure.